# How to let Form2 see how many groupboxes there are in Form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 Windows Forms .

`Form1` has checkboxes within groupboxes.

Whichever checked checkboxes are moved to listBox1 in `Form2`.

I'm trying to write a code that allows `Form2` to see how many groupboxes there are in `Form1`. Can someone give me hint?

(Form1)

```
form2.Populatelist(
                   groupBox1,
                   groupBox2
                  );
```

(Form2)

```
public void Test(params GroupBox[] groupboxes)
        {
            for(int i=0;**# of groupboxes in Form1**;i++)
            {
                var checkBoxes = groupboxes[i].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

                foreach(var checkBox in checkBoxes)
                {
                    if(checkBox.Checked==true)
                    {
                        if(checkBox.Checked==true)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox.Text);
                        }

                        if(listBox1.Items.Count>0)
                        {
                            listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a count of group boxes and so expose it as public property in Form1 like

```
public int GroupBoxCount { get; set; }
```

Pass an instance of Form1 in Form2 like

```
Form2 frm = new From2(this);
```

then you can access it like

```
for(int i=0; i < frm1.GroupBoxCount;i++)
```

Comment: is there a way to get a total number of groupbox in a Form1 even they are within tabControl1?

Comment: @user2521723, irrespective of where control are present you can get them either manually or programatically setting the property as pointed in answer. you can get it from tabcontrols `controls` collection.

Comment: I'm trying to find all the groupboxes in the form dynamically (regardless of how many tabs there are). I think I know how to count the controls using incrementing i, but is there a syntax for it like Form1.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().Count ??

Comment: @user2521723, you can do that but not exactly that cause your groupboxes are present in tabcontrols and not directly under form container. Hope you got the point.